# Question on Triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

In  a right triangle, the length of hypotenuse is $c$. The centers of three circles of radius $c/5$ are found at its vertices. Find the radius of the fourth circle which touches the three given circles and doesn't enclose them.

Comment: I found the radius. Now what?

Comment: @TheChaz: Can you please write proof

Comment: Why the upvote? (This is me "telling", btw)

Comment: @TheChaz: You parenthesized remark is completely cryptic.  Your question is not: I upvoted it since it seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: @Michael: I see.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The midpoint of the hypotenuse is at a distance of $c/2$ from either of the endpoints of the hypotenuse.  It's not hard to show that it's also at that same distance from the vertex of the right angle.  Therefore a circle centered there that is just big enough to touch the two circles of radius $c/5$ centered at the endpoints of the hypotenuse will also be just big enough to touch that third circle of radius $c/5$ centered at the vertex of the right angle.  So do the arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that the center of the fourth circle is equidistant to each vertex of the triangle. Hence show that the center of the fourth circle is the [circumcenter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circumcenter.html) of the triangle. As the circumradius of a right triangle with hypotenuse $c$ is $c/2$, the radius of the fourth circle is $c/2-c/5$.